# Python ==Dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary by reading an input file where the keys are redundant.

Below is my code:

```
f =open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\Programs\data.txt","rb")
data_op={}


for l in f:
  word=l.rstrip("\n").split(",")
  Comp = word[1]

  op = word[3]

if not data_op.has_key(Comp):
       data_op={Comp:op}

       for kv in data_op.items():
            print kv[0],'\t',kv[1]
```

output:

> AA      15.82
>   AA      23.56

Company names are repeated. I need the Company name to be displayed only once.

Can someone please help me out please?

Comment: Do you think you can format the post just a bit cleaner?

Comment: I have made the changes.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are not updating the existing dictionary.

You could try `data_op.update({Comp:op})` instead of `data_op={Comp:op}`.

I hope this help you.